# Variable from apex class not set in javascript

Tags: apex, commandbutton, javascript-controller, apexactionfunction

My variable is not set in Javascript although it is set in apex:

When I click on save, the method allowSave calls the apex method insertproduct , setting the boolean errorMsg to true if a validation fails.

However, the variable errorMsg stays false in javascript although it is set to true when the validation rule fails on the page.

Here's my code(relevant code):

My controller:

```
public class manageProduct {

public Product__c product {
    get;
    set;
}
public String caseId {
    get;
    set;
}
public String productId {
    get;
    set;
}
public product__c newproduct {
    get;
    set;
}
public Boolean errorMsg {
    get;
    set;
}
public manageProduct(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    errorMsg = false;
    product = new product__c();
    newproduct = new product__c();
    caseId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('Id');
    productId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('productId') != null ? System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('productId') : null;
    if (caseId != null) {
        product.case__c = caseId;
    }
}

public void insertproduct() {
    if (productId != null) {
        list < product__c > productToUpdate = [select id, Description__c, Comment__c
            From product__c
            where id =: productId
        ];
        if (productToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            newproduct = productToUpdate[0];
        }
    } else {
        newproduct = new product__c();
    }

    newproduct.product_Description__c = product.product_Description__c != null ? product.product_Description__c : '';
    newproduct.Comment__c = product.Comment__c != null ? product.Comment__c : '';

    if (productId != null) {
        try {
            update newproduct;
            system.debug('updating');
        } catch (System.DmlException ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error updating product.' + ex.getDmlMessage(0)));
            errorMsg = true;
        }
    } else {
        newproduct.case__c = product.case__c;
        try {
            insert newproduct;
            system.debug('inserting');
        } catch (System.DmlException ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error creating new product: ' + ex.getDmlMessage(0)));
            errorMsg = true;
            system.debug('errorMsg>>' + errorMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="manageProduct" sidebar="false" showheader="false" title="product">
<style>

</style>

<apex:form id="theMainForm">
    <apex:actionfunction name="insertproduct" action="{!insertproduct}" rerender="theMainForm,errMessages,test" />
    <apex:pageBlock id="test">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <div>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="javascript:return allowSave();" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="javascript:CloseTab();" />
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:outputPanel id="errMessages">
            <apex:messages></apex:messages>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <table class="detailList">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        {!$Label.Description}
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataCol">
                        <apex:inputfield style="width:350px; height: 70px;position:relative;" id="description" value="{!product.Description__c}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!$Label.Comment_product}
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataCol">
                        <apex:inputfield style="width:500px; height: 100px" id="comment" value="{!product.Comment__c}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/36.0/integration.js" />
<script>
    function allowSave() {
        console.log('Allow save');

        insertproduct();
        console.log('error message>' + {!errorMsg
        });
        redirect();

        return false;
    }

    function redirect() {
        alert({!errorMsg
        });

        if ({!errorMsg
            } != 'true') {
            var wholeURL = window.location.href;

            if (wholeURL.indexOf("inConsole=true") > 0) {
                console.log('sf console');
                sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(tab) {
                    if (tab.id == 'null') {
                        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/{!Case.Id}', true);
                    } else {
                        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(tab.id, '/{!Case.Id}', true);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('sf setup');
                window.location = '/{!Case.Id}';
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be a conflict between my actionfunction and commandbutton

When I removed the actionfunction to use only the commandbutton, it works
Somehow, the errorMsg update is lost when rerender is called on the actionfunction

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insertProduct}" rerender="theMainForm" oncomplete="redirect();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding pattern I have seen before.

A guess at the cause is that in your `apex:actionfunction` the section Ids that you re-render do not result in your `<script>...</script>` block being re-rendered so the original value of `{!errorMsg}` remains. Move that JavaScript inside one of the sections that is re-rendered or surround it with an `apex:outputPanel` whose Id you add to the re-render Ids.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. I re-rendered the outputpanel (containing my script) in actionfunction but my variable is still false

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{! }` binding syntax in JavaScript on a VisualForce page, the browser only interprets it once. So the changes in the Apex controller are not propagating: the browser simply sees the initial value as permanently there.

There's more: `<apex:actionFunction>` executes asynchronously, so the code executed immediately afterwards would not see the change in value even if the JS variable did update. However it does support a `oncomplete` attribute that runs a JS function after the request completes.

So what you could do is, initialize a JS variable `errorMsg` early in the page:

```
<script>var errorMsg;</script>
```

And then **inside one of the blocks that gets re-rendered**, have a script block that copies the server variable:

```
<script>errorMsg = {!errorMsg};</script>
```

You'll want to break up your `allowSave` function into two, one that triggers the Apex method:

```
function allowSave() {
    console.log('Allow save');

    insertproduct();
}
```

And one that is marked as `oncomplete` for this `apex:actionFunction`:

```
function callbackSave() {
    console.log('Allow save');

    insertproduct();
    console.log('error message>' + errorMsg);
    redirect();
}
```

And finally all other references to `{!errorMsg}` become just `errorMsg`. Note, mind you, that you won't be able to return values from these functions like you were hoping to from `allowSave`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but now the variable errorMsg becomes true after redirect() has been called.
I need it to be refreshed before redirect is called.
Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Hmm so you are saying that the `oncomplete` triggers before the `rerender`? In that case you'd need to use something other than `oncomplete`.